# how to test multicast with socat on one machine

Tags: networking, socat, multicast

I'm a linux beginner and trying to test multicast with socat on Ubuntu which works.
A bit "too well" actually (or I'm misunderstanding something fundamental)

my network looks that (ifconfig, abbreviated)

```
ens33 - 192.168.2.10
lo - 127.0.0.1
vboxnet0 - 5 - 192.168.56.1 and up to 192.168.1.1
vboxnet6 - 192.168.1.1
vboxnet7 - 10.0.1.1
vboxnet8 - 192.88.99.1
```

I start socat in two consoles like that
receiver
`socat -d -d UDP-RECVFROM:6666,ip-add-membership=233.168.0.100:192.68.56.1:ens33,fork EXEC:hostname`

sender
`socat -d -d STDIO UDP4-DATAGRAM:233.18.0.100:6666,range=192.168.56.100/30`

It doesn't matter what I choose as multicast address, as long as they match.
And I have to specify the interface on the receiver side for it to work.

Like I said at the beginning the receiver receives messages and that's the problem.

If I'm not mistaken it shouldn't because it is not i the defined range of `192.168.56.100/30` which translates to `192.168.56.101 - 192.168.56.103`
the receiver always receives packages no matter what IP.

Am I misunderstanding what `range` actually does?
What am I missing?

I suspect it has something to with being on the same device (routing).

Comment: It would be interesting to know what you think multicast is for.

Comment: as far as I know it's for sending packets to a subset of addresses which have registered beforehand with the multicast address. 
Instead of broadcasting packets to everybody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multicasting is behaving as it is supposed to work.

When you are signaling an interface to listen for a multicast address, in fact, you are associating the underlying interface with that address and not the IP address of that interface.

So as long as you are sharing the same physical/virtual medium/network, all the interfaces associated with the multicast address will receive a multicast transmission.

Comment: recommended reading material https://www.amazon.com/TCP-Illustrated-Protocols-Addison-Wesley-Professional/dp/0321336313

Comment: thanks, but then it seems I completly misunderstood socats range parameter.
Meaning: the range parameter filters incoming packets.
I focused on that parameter way too hard (in the wrong way)...

Comment: just an additional hint for others. Don't use `224.0.0.1` as multicast adress like described here -> http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat-multicast.html#ALLSYSTEMS.
Every socket is automatically member of this group. Just use something different.
Probably something not found with `netstat -gn` before you start testing

Comment: @Arikael There are other groups, like the ALL ROUTERS. You should not be abusing 244/8, for several reasons. See this "The 239.0.0.0/8 range is assigned by RFC 2365 for private use within an organization. Per the RFC, packets destined to administratively scoped IPv4 multicast addresses do not cross administratively defined organizational boundaries, and administratively scoped IPv4 multicast addresses are locally assigned and do not have to be globally unique. " . I would suggest opening other questions for related subjects, and not using comments.